# Blinking question mark folder after updating from Mojave to Catalina

Tags: macos, mojave, startup, software-update, catalina

I used macOS Mojave on mid-2014 MacBook Pro before update. While installation it forced me to restart. After restart nightmare has been started.
The Blinking question mark folder has appeared on my screen.

I tried,

- Reset SMC and NVRAM (With all combinations these are find on internet and apple support page.)
- Accsess local and network recovery (with all key combinations)
- Access to time machine restore (with all key combinations)
- Mojave installation USB stick (that USB works we tried another Macs)
- External disk that includes pre installed mojave (that external OS works well we ran on other Macs)
- Unplug all battery power (black reset)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Dealing with the same issue except mine is `stop` sign and blinks to folder, with verbose mode I get ‘no CSFDE users processed’ and that’s all.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204323 See this support article for blinking question mark on folder. " it means your Mac can't find its system software." cc:@ymg

Comment: @ymg does not start even with verbose mode

Comment: Same problem here. Today, after installing Catalina update, the pc restarted and start showing the folder blinking. Don't know what to do, i've tryed all keyboard combinations and nothing works, even with external keyboard!

Comment: Same problem here. I have tried all keyboard combinations- CMD+R, CMD+Ctrl+R, CMD+Alt+R, +P, CMD+V, but to no avail. I have tried Alt alone. The only thing that happens is that there is a flashing folder icon with a question mark on it 5 minutes after pressing the power button. There is no start up chime. It does not detect USB.

Comment: @Jakomys were you able to resolve it. I found another question here where they had to switch the motherboard. Seems like a nightmare update.

Comment: @Jakomys Link to the question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368304/catalina-beta-7-bricked-my-macbook-pro

Comment: Hi @Berkay, did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @Chang we send the MBP to technical service they changed the keyboard and said we reset core SMC software.